# Automating connecting to lxc container and executing commands inside the container

Tags: python, linux, bash, virtualization, lxc

Hi I am trying to automate lxc container creation/starting/stopping and executing commands inside them via script (Bash/Python). I was able to create a container which is a very simple step

```
lxc-create -t ubuntu -n CONTAINER1
```

Now I want to start this container and login to it using a script. I tried expect to pass the username and password which did not work.

```
lxc-start -n CONTAINER1
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: so what's the error message you got, don't let us to guess.

Comment: And show us the expect script you wrote and its error message.

Comment: And have a look at http://lxc.teegra.net/: `7.6.1. /etc/rc.d/lxc`

Answer (score 0):

First, start the container with the -d option in a script, then call the script below.

I create a small script with "expect" that can login the container, perform a ls -tral and then logout.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh root@CONTAINER1
expect "password" {
  send "root\r" }
expect "# " {send "ls -tral\r" }
expect "# " {send "logout\r" }
```

And yes, the default password for root is root, and yes, on my systems I changed them al :-)